# Winform dropdown box floats on tablet

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, tablet

I have this winform application that I run on tablet. In my scenario I have two dropdowns and two textboxes on my screen. When I focus on the textbox the keyboard appears from below and makes my screen smaller and pushes the screen upward.

Now when I click on the dropdown the 'pop-up' box appears. Then the keyboard disappears and after it disappears my screen comes back to its original size, the dropdown/textboxes come down, but the dropdown 'pop-box' doesn't come down and stays in its initial position.

My initial thought was I'm gonna hook into the LocationChanged event and update the location, but the issue is the dropdown is inside couple of layers. Here's the structure:

```
MyScreenView
   MyUserControl
      MyDropDown // RadDropdown if that matters
      MyTextBox
   MyUserControl
      MyDropDown
      MyTextBox
```

Now, the problem is the size of MyScreenView is changing, but since the dropdown's location is relative to it's parent, it doesn't invoke the LocationChanged event at all. NOTE: I'm using RadDropDownList, which has a ListElement, the 'pop-up' box.

Does anyone have any answer to how can I keep the whole dropdown together?

Comment: If `the size of MyScreenView is changing` can't you just use the event handler from that and update the dropdown from there? Why would the event handler need to be on the dropdown or partent itself?

Comment: @EpicKip took an attempt to do that. My usercontrols are added programmatically on code behind, and at that time I don't know which dropdown is clicked. So I ended up updating the location for both usercontrols -> dropdowns. It still didn't work, and I'm assuming it's because the control.Location was still relative to it's parent.

Comment: You can make a delegate event, that way you can send events to parents of the user control